# Android Compose: Is there a work around for painterResource not supporting .webp file ? Vector images work fine

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use a .webp drawable that is available in my project to use it as card icon. The icon wouldn't show up right and when I was looking up for the issue, I realized that *painterResource* doesn't support the id for a .webp file yet. Is there a way this can be achieved? Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webp is very much supported. You are probably using `Icon` instead of `Image`. `Icon` is material component that applies tint by default

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was using Icon. But then I tried Image and it worked like a charm. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I feel like Google is a little vague about icon component in their docs

Comment: Can you please share the code how you did?. Still I am not able to load webp image in Image too.